# async_dirty on replicated table

Tags: transactions, erlang, mnesia

Say I have a Mnesia table, T, which holds `{T, Key, Value},` replicated on two nodes, A and B, and `dirty_write` is defined as:

```
dirty_write(T, Tuple) ->
    Fun = fun() ->
                  mnesia:write(T, Tuple, write)
          end,
    mnesia:activity(async_dirty, Fun, [], SomeMod).
```

and `R1 = {T, 1, 2}`, `R2 = {T, 1, 3}` are two records, if I perform (may be concurrently):

```
dirty_write(T, R1) %% on node A
dirty_write(T, R2) %% on node B
```

will this introduce some kind of inconsistency/error on T?

Answer (score 0):

I find your records `R1 = {1, 2}`, `R2 = {1, 3}` to be a bit unconventional, because mnesia convention would make `R1 = {T, 1, 2}`, `R2 = {T, 1, 3}` more common, but not necessarily actually dysfunctional for an appropriate implementation of your callback module. Still, your code, like this, might not be what other Erlang developers expect.

For the example you provide, it's not of course clear what the key is necessarily, but probably the most reasonable guess is the first element of your 'records', being `1` in this case. So that means you're updating the same record on 2 nodes.

This being the case, I see no reason for any risk of inconsistency as a result of the 2 transactions themselves; there's no risk your table will contain anything actually invalid as such, but of course one will overwrite the other and neither writer knows which will win. PROBABLY if you feel you want to do an async dirty write in this way, then I expect you've decided it doesn't matter which one wins...

However... other transactions/operations that read or otherwise use the record you are updating may potentially access EITHER of the values of records written, OR use the value before either of those writes, and then do whatever they do having done so... so then the question is (and it's completely use case dependent) could any other operations (transactional or not) be adversely affected by this level of uncertainty. The main risk here is that, for example, some other record might be written on the basis of the record `{T, 1, 2}` being written, but by the time all is said and done, it's actually `{T, 2, 3}` that prevails... This might or might not be possible for your application, and it might or might not be a problem!

There's a reason mnesia offers different levels of security vs performance (async dirty, sync dirty and full on sync transactions), which is because only the end developer / integrator has enough knowledge to decide what security and performance is required.